# R Summarize Many Categorical Variables Separably

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
data = data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B","B"),
  category1 = c("X", "Y", "Z", "Z", "X"),
  category2 = c("M", "Q", "M", "M", "L")
)

data %>% group_by(group, category2) %>% summarize(count = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)*100)

data %>% group_by(group, category1) %>% summarize(count = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)*100)
```

I wish to summarize category1 and category2. I can do it separately like shown but i do not know how to combine them and get the same result.
I try this but it is not correct:

```
data %>% group_by(group, category1, category2) %>% summarize(count = n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(percent = count/sum(count)*100)
```

The desire output would be a table that has the frequency and percent of each category variable by group independent of the other category variable...

Answer (score 1):

If we `pivot_longer` first, we can combine them.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
pivot_longer(data, cols = -group, names_to = "category") %>%
  summarize(count = n(), .by = c(group, category, value)) %>%
  mutate(percent = 100 * count / sum(count), .by = c(group, category))
# # A tibble: 9 × 5
#   group category  value count percent
#   <chr> <chr>     <chr> <int>   <dbl>
# 1 A     category1 X         1    33.3
# 2 A     category2 M         2    66.7
# 3 A     category1 Y         1    33.3
# 4 A     category2 Q         1    33.3
# 5 A     category1 Z         1    33.3
# 6 B     category1 Z         1    50  
# 7 B     category2 M         1    50  
# 8 B     category1 X         1    50  
# 9 B     category2 L         1    50
```

This is using `.by=` from `dplyr_1.1.0`; if you have an older dplyr, modify that to be:

```r
pivot_longer(data, cols = -group, names_to = "category") %>%
  group_by(group, category, value) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(group, category) %>%
  mutate(percent = 100 * count / sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(Note that since `group_by` defaults to `.add=FALSE`, we don't need to `ungroup() %>% group_by(..)` for the new grouping.)

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data.frame(
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  category1 = c("X", "Y", "Z", "Z", "X"),
  category2 = c("M", "Q", "M", "M", "L")
)

library(tidyverse)

to_do_list <- c(
  "category2",
  "category1"
)

names(to_do_list) <- to_do_list

(result_df <- map(to_do_list, \(x){
  data |>
    group_by(group,
      category_value = !!sym(x)
    ) |>
    summarize(count = n()) |>
    ungroup() |>
    group_by(group) |>
    mutate(percent = count / sum(count) * 100)
}) |> list_rbind(names_to = "category_source"))
```

```
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  category_source group category_value count percent
  <chr>           <chr> <chr>          <int>   <dbl>
1 category2       A     M                  2    66.7
2 category2       A     Q                  1    33.3
3 category2       B     L                  1    50  
4 category2       B     M                  1    50  
5 category1       A     X                  1    33.3
6 category1       A     Y                  1    33.3
7 category1       A     Z                  1    33.3
8 category1       B     X                  1    50  
9 category1       B     Z                  1    50
```